# Couchbase : How to Delete Multiple Documents By Using Document ID pattern

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am new to Couchbase database.

I have populated a bucket with 10,000 documents and I want to remove these documents using document Id pattern by using N1Ql delete query.  For example the keys are like :ao.sl3:eid:89049032000001000000000016677381. So I want to use a pattern , something like ':ao.sl3:eid%' to delete all the documents.

On Couchbase Web UI, my document looks like below image - 
[image]

I want to use CouchBase web UI query editor to delete the documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a [primary index](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/createprimaryindex.html) to do this, but you can simply [use the `LIKE` operator](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/comparisonops.html):

```
DELETE
FROM mybucketname
WHERE META().id LIKE ':ao.sl3:eid%'
```

Some things to keep in mind:

- A primary index is a very dangerous thing to have in production. If this is a one-time thing, make sure to remove that primary index after your `DELETE` has run.
- If this is something you will be doing in production on a regular basis, you may want to consider an alternate approach. Depending on your use case, you may want to look at TTL, N1QL paging, eventing, or an alternate data model that can use a more efficient index.

Comment: I am doing it on test setup. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why is having primary index such a bad thing? If it will be used exclusively for deleting documents with given prefix (`WHERE META().id LIKE 'prefix.%'`), is it still a bad thing? Why would it hurt performance when writes and reads are using the exact key (so they would not require an index)?

Comment: The problem with a primary index is that it will be scanning every single document in the bucket. I'm not saying *never* use it, but just be careful. Even if you only *plan* to use it with one particular cleanup operation that runs occasionally, the index is still out there. If someone modifies/makes a mistake in an unrelated query, it could fall back to using the primary index, which will result in a scan of every document.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a few years, but I am just following up any any loose ends, as [Matthew Groves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40015/matthew-groves) indicated you could use the Couchbase Eventing service.

The function to do what you want is quite trivial 4 lines (8 if you count comments).

```
// example the keys are like :ao.sl3:eid:89049032000001000000000016677381
// delete any key starting with a pattern like ":ao.sl3:eid:"
// make a binding of a bucket alias called src_bkt in read+write mode 
// then deploy with a Feed Boundary of Everything.
function OnUpdate(doc, meta) {
    if (!meta.id.startsWith(':ao.sl3:eid:')) return;
    delete src_bkt[meta.id];
}
```

For more information on Couchbase Eventing refer to [eventing-overview](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-overview.html) and [eventing-examples](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-examples.html)